# Запрашиваю размер JSON массива из двух объектов, но выдает 2ку 10 раз

Tags: javascript, json

Есть JSON файл, в нём массив из двух объектов

```
[
  {
    "name": "Герасемчукова Максимилиана",
    "status": "Безработная",
    "skills": ["Слесарь-сантехник"],
    "birthday": "27.01.1983",
    "age": "33 года",
    "zodiac": "Водолей",
    "response": "Плотник 03.02.2022",
    "date-iupload": "25.09.2019",
    "resource-upload": "vsevn.ru",
    "phone": "+79599999999",
    "phone-operator": "Теле 2",
    "phone-region": "Нижнегородская область",
    "live-region": "Балахна/Нижнегородская область",
    "who-append": "Отклик",
    "online": "14.10.2021 10:15",
    "comments": [
      "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nemo?",
      "Lorem  dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
    ],
    "operator-photo": {
      "src": "../assets/images/operator-photo/photo.png",
      "alt": "operator"
    },
    "photo": {
      "src": "../assets/images/applicant/photo.png",
      "alt": "applicant"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Герасемчукова Жуковка",
    "status": "Безработная",
    "skills": ["Слесарь-сантехник"],
    "birthday": "27.01.1983",
    "age": "33 года",
    "zodiac": "Водолей",
    "response": "Плотник 03.02.2022",
    "date-iupload": "25.09.2019",
    "resource-upload": "vsevn.ru",
    "phone": "+79599999999",
    "phone-operator": "Теле 2",
    "phone-region": "Нижнегородская область",
    "live-region": "Балахна/Нижнегородская область",
    "who-append": "Отклик",
    "online": "14.10.2021 10:15",
    "comments": [
      "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, nemo?",
      "Lorem  dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit."
    ],
    "operator-photo": {
      "src": "../assets/images/operator-photo/photo.png",
      "alt": "operator"
    },
    "photo": {
      "src": "../assets/images/applicant/photo.png",
      "alt": "applicant"
    }
  }
]
```

Я хочу получить его размер, ожидаю получить 2, но вместо этого в консоли он выводит этот размер 10 раз, вместо 2.

```
import myJson from "../../utils/applicant-information.json" assert { type: "json" };

class CreateApplicant {
  constructor(domParent) {
    this.container = domParent;
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.initElements();
    this.createTemplate();
  }

  initElements() {
    this.countApplicant = myJson.length;
  }

  createTemplate() {
    console.log(this.countApplicant);
  }
}

export default CreateApplicant;
```

Comment: Дык непонятно, может вы создаете 10 экземпляров класса, вызывая 10 раз конструктор.

Comment: Да всё верно, спасибо, совсем забыл про это.

Comment: Все вроде адекватно работает, у меня выдает length = 2. Для начала выведите в консоль сам myJson, может, у вас вместо массива что-то другое выдается.

Comment: @Инквизитор там вопрос не в размере, а в том, что размер выводится 10 раз